# getting data from api_key in django restframework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am going to make a small app but I do not know how to do it that's why I need you advice. For example, I have a `api_key` like that `API_KEY='AdsbdmAYugjhnvcvbnRDgfcvbnb'` from third party service, let's imagine this computer service group and I need to do is that when I post a computer model number (i.e XS54125) and it should return **name, manufacturer, produced date, etc** and I should save this details in the database but I do not know how to implement this app. Can you give me idea please? because I have never done this kind of app before. If anything is still unclear please let me know I'll try to explain in more detail. Thank you beforehand!

Comment: **Create a view**, that accepts the *computer model* and send requests to the third-party service from the view and receive the response. You can use Django models to save the response/data into your Database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the [django rest framework tutorial](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/) to create an endpoint that basically do what you need, it means:

1. Create your project
2. Create your api app
3. Set in the core project your `API_KEY` in the `settings.py` file using `configparser` (i.e: getting the credentials from a `settings.ini` file)
4. Install django rest framework
5. Create a `Computer` model with all the attributes that you'll need (model number, name, manufacturer, produced date, etc)
6. Create in your api.py file a view (inside of your api app), where you'll make a request to the third party service (i.e with requests library and if the response is in Json format, manipulate the response as you need) and in the urls.py set the endpoint url with POST method. This can be a Class that inherit from `viewsets.ViewSet` instead of `viewsets.ModelViewSet`, because you don't need to extract data from a model, but you'll be able to save the response in your `Computer` model. Optionally you can create a Serializer to save the data into your `Computer` model.

Comment: thanks for the answer! I think requests library I should give url right? or can I give api_key? if so how can I do this can you tell plz?

Comment: Probably you'll need to do something like this: ```response = requests.get("<third_party_service_url>/?key=API_KEY")``` but you should check the third party service documentation to make sure of how to pass your key to the request